# Efficient push of partial bytes on to std::queue

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, stl, queue

I have an `std::queue` holding messages which can be a variable size:

```
using Element = `std::array<std::byte, 1'000>;
std::queue<Element> _queue;
```

Most of the time I don't have 1000 bytes, I probably have 200 or 100.

At the moment I'm pushing like this:

```
// newElement only uses 100 of the 1,000 bytes
_queue.push(newElement);
```

which I assume allocates AND copies 1,000 bytes.

Is there a way to make this more efficient/avoid allocating AND copying the unused 900 bytes?

Comment: FWIW, `std::queue` is already doing dynamic allocation so you might as well use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Problem is I would have no idea where the data has actually been allocated. So every message will be allocated on the heap.

Comment: You already have that though.  `std::queue` is going to allocate each element in it dynamically, so your array is going to be allocated on the heap as is.  If you use a vector instead of an array, you'll save all that empty space.

Comment: There is also [std::queue::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/emplace).